# Add capture group values in a PowerShell replace loop

Tags: regex, powershell

Needing to replace a string in multiple text files with the same string , except with capture group 2 replaced by the sum of itself and capture group 4.

String: `Total amount $11.39 | Change $0.21`
Desired Result: `Total amount $11.60 | Change $0.21`

I have attempted several methods.  Here is my last attempt which seems  to run without error, but without any changes to the string .

```cs
$Originalfolder = "$ENV:userprofile\Documents\folder\"
$Originalfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "$Originalfolder\*"

$RegexPattern = '\b(Total\s\amount\s\$)(\d?\d?\d?\d?\d\.?\d?\d?)(\s\|\sChange\s\$)(\d?\d?\d\.?\d?\d?)\b'
$Substitution = {
    Param($Match)
    $Result = $GP1 + $Sumtotal + $GP3 + $Change
    $GP1 = $Match.Groups[1].Value
    $Total = $Match.Groups[2].Value
    $GP3 = $Match.Groups[3].Value
    $Change = $Match.Groups[4].Value
    $Sumtotal = ($Total + $Change)
    return [string]$Result
}

foreach ($file in $Originalfiles) {
    $Lines = Get-Content $file.FullName
    $Lines | ForEach-Object {
        [Regex]::Replace($_, $RegexPattern, $Substitution)
    } | Set-Content $file.FullName
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, your regular expression doesn't even match what you're trying to replace, because you escaped the `a` in `amount`:

```
\b(Total\s\amount\s\$)(\d?\d?\d?...
#         ^^
```

`\a` is an [escape sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-escapes-in-regular-expressions) that matches the "alarm" or "bell" character `\u0007`.

Also, if you want to calculate the sum of two captures you need to convert them to numeric values first, otherwise the `+` operator would just concatenate the two strings.

```
$Total    = $Match.Groups[2].Value
$Change   = $Match.Groups[4].Value
$Sumtotal = $Total + $Change                  # gives 11.390.21
$Sumtotal = [double]$Total + [double]$Change  # gives 11.6
```

And you need to build `$Result` *after* you defined the other variables, otherwise the replacement function would just return an empty string.

Change this:

```
$RegexPattern = '\b(Total\s\amount\s\$)(\d?\d?\d?\d?\d\.?\d?\d?)(\s\|\sChange\s\$)(\d?\d?\d\.?\d?\d?)\b'
$Substitution = {
    param ($Match)
    $Result = $GP1 + $Sumtotal + $GP3 + $Change
    $GP1 = $Match.Groups[1].Value
    $Total = $Match.Groups[2].Value
    $GP3 = $Match.Groups[3].Value
    $Change = $Match.Groups[4].Value
    $Sumtotal = ($Total + $Change)
    return [string]$Result
}
```

into this:

```
$RegexPattern = '\b(Total\samount\s\$)(\d?\d?\d?\d?\d\.?\d?\d?)(\s\|\sChange\s\$)(\d?\d?\d\.?\d?\d?)\b'
$Substitution = {
    Param($Match)
    $GP1 = $Match.Groups[1].Value
    $Total = [double]$Match.Groups[2].Value
    $GP3 = $Match.Groups[3].Value
    $Change = [double]$Match.Groups[4].Value
    $Sumtotal = ($Total + $Change)
    $Result = $GP1 + $Sumtotal + $GP3 + $Change
    return [string]$Result
}
```

and the code will mostly do what you want. "Mostly", because it will not format the calculated number to double decimals. You need to do that yourself. Use the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0#special-operators) (`-f`) and change your replacement function to something like this:

```
$Substitution = {
    Param($Match)
    $GP1      = $Match.Groups[1].Value
    $Total    = [double]$Match.Groups[2].Value
    $GP3      = $Match.Groups[3].Value
    $Change   = [double]$Match.Groups[4].Value
    $Sumtotal = $Total + $Change
    return ('{0}{1:n2}{2}{3:n2}' -f $GP1, $Sumtotal, $GP3, $Change)
}
```

---

As a side note: the sub-expression `\d?\d?\d?\d?\d\.?\d?\d?` could be shortened to `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` (one or more digit, optionally followed by a period and one or more digits) or, more exactly, to `\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{0,2})?` (one to four digits, optionally followed by a period and up to 2 digits).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain it.  . This works perfectly . I'm still very green when working with  PS , .Net and Expressions.  . I'm pretty happy I got as close as I did  to a solution really.  I will read up on the -f operator and the [double] cast you used as its my first time seeing an example of them.

Answer (score 0):

here's how I'd do it:  this is pulled out of a larger script that regularly scans a directory for files, then does a similar manipulation, and I've changed variables quickly to obfuscate, so shout if it doesn't work and I'll take a more detailed look tomorrow.

It takes a backup of each file as well, and works on a temp copy before renaming.

Note it also sends an email alert (code at the end) to say if any processing was done - this is because it's designed to run as as scheduled task in the original

```
$backupDir = "$pwd\backup"
$stringToReplace = "."
$newString = "."

$files = @(Get-ChildItem $directoryOfFiles)

$intFiles = $files.count

$tmpExt = ".tmpDataCorrection"
$DataCorrectionAppend = ".DataprocessBackup"

    foreach ($file in $files) {
    $content = Get-Content -Path ( $directoryOfFiles + $file )
    # Check whether there are any instances of the string
    If (!($content -match $stringToReplace)) { 
        # Do nothing if we didn't match
    }
    Else {
        #Create another blank temporary file which the corrected file contents will be written to
        $tmpFileName_DataCorrection = $file.Name + $tmpExt_DataCorrection
        $tmpFile_DataCorrection = $directoryOfFiles + $tmpFileName_DataCorrection
        New-Item -ItemType File -Path $tmpFile_DataCorrection
        foreach ( $line in $content ) {
            If ( $line.Contains("@")) {
                Add-Content -Path $tmpFile_DataCorrection -Value $line.Replace($stringToReplace,$newString)
                #Counter to know whether any processing was done or not
                $processed++
                }
            Else {
                Add-Content -Path $tmpFile_DataCorrection -Value $line
            }
        }   
        #Backup (rename) the original file, and rename the temp file to be the same name as the original
        Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName ($file.FullName + $DataCorrectionAppend) -Force -Confirm:$false       
        Move-Item -Path ( $file.FullName + $DataCorrectionAppend ) -Destination backupDir -Force -Confirm:$false
        Rename-Item -Path $tmpFile_DataCorrection -NewName $file.FullName -Force -Confirm:$false

        # Check to see if anything was done, then populate a variable to use in final email alert if there was
        If (!$processed) {
            #no message as did nothing
            }
        Else {
            New-Variable -Name ( "processed" + $file.Name) -Value $strProcessed
            }

    } # Out of If loop
    }
```